# Storing from inside a loop a borrowed value to container in outer scope?

Tags: rust

I set myself a little task to acquire some basic Rust knowledge. The task was:

> Read some key-value pairs from stdin and put them into a hashmap.

This, however, turned out to be a trickier challenge than expected. Mainly due to the understanding of  lifetimes. The following code is what I currently have after a few experiments, but the compiler just doesn't stop yelling at me.

```
use std::io;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut input       = io::stdin(); 
    let mut lock        = input.lock(); 
    let mut lines_iter  = lock.lines();

    let mut map         = HashMap::new();

    for line in lines_iter {
        let text                = line.ok().unwrap();
        let kv_pair: Vec<&str>  = text.words().take(2).collect();

        map.insert(kv_pair[0], kv_pair[1]);
    }

    println!("{}", map.len());
}
```

The compiler basically says:

```
`text` does not live long enough
```

As far as I understand, this is because the lifetime of 'text' is limited to the scope of the loop.
The key-value pair that I'm extracting within the loop is therefore also bound to the loops boundaries. Thus, inserting them to the outer map would lead to a dangling pointer since 'text' will be destroyed after each iteration. (Please tell me if I'm wrong)

The big question is: How to solve this issue?

My intuition says:

Make an "owned copy" of the key value pair and "expand" it's lifetime to the outer scope .... but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The lifetime of 'text' is limited to the scope of the loop. The key-value pair that I'm extracting within the loop is therefore also bound to the loops boundaries. Thus, inserting them to the outer map would lead to an dangling pointer since 'text' will be destroyed after each iteration.

Sounds right to me.

> Make an "owned copy" of the key value pair.

An owned `&str` is a `String`:

```
map.insert(kv_pair[0].to_string(), kv_pair[1].to_string());
```

**Edit**

The original code is below, but I've updated the answer above to be more idiomatic

```
map.insert(String::from_str(kv_pair[0]), String::from_str(kv_pair[1]));
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves my issue. I have always read about String being an "owned versions" of &str  .... but now I understand one of its "real-life" applications.

Comment: I just found out that you can also call x.to_string() on a &str instead of doing String::from_str(x).

Comment: @forgemo not only can you, it's considered more idiomatic.

Comment: @SteveKlabnik @forgemo I got bit by [slow performance](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/19708) of `to_string` so I've been avoiding its use. For my code, I saw performance increases of ~13% by switching.

Comment: @Shepmaster yes, some recent changes have landed in the last few days which should help with that

Comment: What about `to_owned`? That should be as fast as `String::from_str`, but fewer characters to type (even less than `to_string`)

Answer (score 1):

In **Rust `1.1`** the function `words` was marked as deprecated. Now you should use `split_whitespace`.

Here is an alternative solution which is a bit more functional and idiomatic (works with `1.3`).

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();

    // iterate over all lines, "change" the lines and collect into `HashMap`
    let map: HashMap<_, _> = stdin.lock().lines().filter_map(|line_res| {
        // convert `Result` to `Option` and map the `Some`-value to a pair of
        // `String`s
        line_res.ok().map(|line| {
            let kv: Vec<_> = line.split_whitespace().take(2).collect();
            (kv[0].to_owned(), kv[1].to_owned())
        })
    }).collect();

    println!("{}", map.len());
}
```