# Insert into hashmap in a loop

Tags: for-loop, rust, hashmap, ownership

I'm opening a CSV file and reading it using `BufReader` and splitting each line into a vector. Then I try to insert or update the count in a `HashMap` using a specific column as key.

```
let mut map: HashMap<&str, i32> = HashMap::new();

let reader = BufReader::new(input_file);
for line in reader.lines() {
    let s = line.unwrap().to_string();
    let tokens: Vec<&str> = s.split(&d).collect(); // <-- `s` does not live long enough
    if tokens.len() > c {
        println!("{}", tokens[c]);
        let count = map.entry(tokens[c].to_string()).or_insert(0);
        *count += 1;
    }
}
```

The compiler kindly tells me `s` is shortlived. [Storing from inside a loop a borrowed value to container in outer scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473583/storing-from-inside-a-loop-a-borrowed-value-to-container-in-outer-scope) suggests "owning" the string, so I tried to change

```
let count = map.entry(tokens[c]).or_insert(0);
```

to

```
let count = map.entry(tokens[c].to_string()).or_insert(0);
```

but I get the error

```
expected `&str`, found struct `std::string::String`
help: consider borrowing here: `&tokens[c].to_string()`
```

When I prepend ampersand (`&`) the error is

```
creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived
```

There is some deficiency in my Rust knowledge about borrowing. How can I make the hashmap own the string passed as key?

Comment: How did you declare `map`?

Comment: Thank you, added map-declaration. And you solved my problem. I changed the declaration to HashMap<String, i32>. I used a hashmap-example at rust-lang.org that used &str.

Comment: Thank you, I did that as we speak. Can you add that as an answer?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. @Jmb pointed me to the solution. The error was because I had defined the hashmap with &str. When I changed it to String (ie. HashMap<String, i32>) the error went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for this to work is for your map to own the keys. This means that you must change its type from `HasMap<&str, i32>` (which borrows the keys) to `HashMap<String, i32>`. At which point you can call `to_string` to convert your tokens into owned strings:

```
let mut map: HashMap<String, i32> = HashMap::new();

let reader = BufReader::new(input_file);
for line in reader.lines() {
    let s = line.unwrap().to_string();
    let tokens:Vec<&str> = s.split(&d).collect();
    if tokens.len() > c {
        println!("{}", tokens[c]);
        let count = map.entry(tokens[c].to_string()).or_insert(0);
        *count += 1;
    }
}
```

Note however that this means that `tokens[c]` will be duplicated even if it was already present in the map. You can avoid the extra duplication by trying to modify the counter with [`get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut) first, but this requires two lookups when the key is missing:

```
let mut map: HashMap<String, i32> = HashMap::new();

let reader = BufReader::new(input_file);
for line in reader.lines() {
    let s = line.unwrap().to_string();
    let tokens:Vec<&str> = s.split(&d).collect();
    if tokens.len() > c {
        println!("{}", tokens[c]);
        if let Some (count) = map.get_mut (tokens[c]) {
            *count += 1;
        } else {
            map.insert (tokens[c].to_string(), 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know of a solution that would only copy the key when there was no previous entry but still do a single lookup.

Comment: Thank you, it works when I changed Key in HashMap<> to String. Changed the map.entry() so a variant I posted when trying to solve it had map.entry(t). Later changed back to map.entry(tokens[c].to_string()).